# ruby on rails pairing users in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I write a code in Ruby on rails that picks  user X from my database( let say I have a column called 'taskdone'  which accepts only boolean values ...  And user X is true in such column) such that when a new user signs up,   user X is displayed on his profile. And the new user is given a task to complete.  If he
 completes it successfully user X can confirm from his own account that the new user has completed his task by clicking a button which writes a value of true to the new users paid 'task done '  column.  And after user X has confirmed four people,  his value in the column should go back to false.  It's quite complicated please I need someone to help am frustrated searching Google without answers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automating pairing in ruby on rails database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42249553/automating-pairing-in-ruby-on-rails-database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in two ways

1- If you need the information about "which user confirms another user" You can create an association to hold for each user X which other users he has confirmed.

2 - If you won't use these info you can just create a column that counts the number of confirmed users in the Users tabel.

In both cases, After a user confirms another user make a check if he has confirmed 4 users or not using the callback ***after create*** and then update the taskdone column.

```
after_create :update_task_done
```

In the first way do

```
def update_task_done
    if self.confirmed_users.count == 4
        self.update(taskdone: false)
    end
end
```

In the second way

```
def update_task_done
    if self.confirmed_users_count == 4 # notice this is column.
        self.update(taskdone: false)
    end
end
```

Comment: So how can I make the user X.  See the new user he was paired and vise versa.  And also set the activate button to write to database of the new user

Comment: Build an one-to-many [self join](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins) so for each user he has many (users he has confirmed) and belongs to (one user who confirmed him).

Comment: please can you chat me up on WhatsApp? +2348149444456